# ConcurrentModificationException, i want to delete the same names in hashmap values

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap

I want to use this method to delete the same names in HashMap but when i try to compile my code, i get ConcurrentModificationException.

```
public static void removeTheFirstNameDuplicates(HashMap<String, String> map)
    {

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> pair : map.entrySet()){
            String name = pair.getValue();
            removeItemFromMapByValue(map, name);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Don't get confused between compilation errors and run time exceptions/errors.

Comment: And google the exception and exception message. This is a duplicate if I ever saw one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use an "enhanced" for loop such as this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> pair : map.entrySet()){
```

There is really an implicit `Iterator` behind the scenes that gives you a `pair` on each iteration.  [Section 14.14.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) states:

> The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of the form:
>
> ```
> for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
>     VariableModifiersopt TargetType Identifier =
>         (TargetType) #i.next();
>     Statement
> }
> ```

The `Iterator` will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` if anything modifies the collection while it's iterating it, unless you call the [iterator's own `remove()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()), which removes the current element.  You'll have to use an explicit `Iterator`:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> itr = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (itr.hasNext())
{
    Map.Entry<String, String> pair = itr.next();
    if (yourCriteriaIsMet)
    {
        itr.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't modify data structures while iterating over them - see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html.